# Turn of the Transient User Activation feature of Firefox

Tags: firefox, websecurity

Can firefox be configured in the preferences or through the flags not to use the [Transient User Activation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Transient_activation) feature?

I need to call getDisplayMedia() API in the window.load() event from some machines that are owned by me. However, due to the above feature, all similar apis are getting blocked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is not possible to turn this feature off. Note that the Firefox behavior is following what the current web specification says:

> If the relevant global object of this does not have transient activation, return a promise rejected with a DOMException object whose name attribute has the value InvalidStateError.

You can expect other browsers to follow this ["recent"](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1705289) spec behavior change.

[image]